# Complex Join on 2 Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, db2

I have a ZIP Neighborhood Table that goes like this -

```
ZIP     NEIGHBOR
------- --------
01026   01330   
01026   01331   
01026   01332   
01026   01333  
01026   01026
.............
```

Same ZIP can have multiple entries - each entry being with one neighbor. (A ZIP is a neighbor with itself)

I have another table that has info on which ZIPs **do not have** any bakery in the area,

```
ZIP  
-----
01026  
01330 
01331
01332
01333
.....
```

So, we need to find ZIPs which **do not have bakeries** in its neighborhood.

How do we do it?

In this case, we need the output as '01026' - as it doesnt have bakeries in itself and its neighbors

Comment: Hi, Have you tried anything? Doesn't seems complex at all...

Comment: Are you running mysql, or db2? Please use only the relevant tag.

Comment: What is your expected output for this sample data?

Comment: 01026 is in the in NEIGHBOR as in zip your question doens't make any sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want `zip`s from the first table (say `zip_neighborhood`) whose all `neighbor`s can be found in the other table (say `zip_without_bakery`).

If so, you can `left join` the second table, `group by` zip, and use the `having clause` to ensure that all neighbors were found.

```
select n.zip
from zip_neighborhood n
left join zip_without_bakery b on b.zip = n.neighbor
group by n.zip
having max(b.zip is null) = 0
```

Comment: @elysian_seikatsu: I think this should do what you want. I added more explanation to the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood correctly, you just want to filter Table2 (with ZIP's only) from Table1 and exclude all that entries? If that table shall still show the bakeries, you join them and use WHERE NOT condition.

```
SELECT * 
FROM bakerytable, ziponlytable
WHERE NOT bakerytable.zip = ziponlytable.zip
```

Called implicitly join. I love it sind I've seen it the first time.

Selects each columns from both tables, and looks for that condition.